# UIScrollView does not automatically scroll to first responder

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

In a simple test app (no code added, just storyboard), a `UIScrollView` scrolls automatically to show the next text field when it becomes first responder (it doesn't account for the keyboard height, but I'm aware of the fixes for that). However, in my more complex app, this built-in scrolling never occurs. Otherwise the scrollView functions perfectly.

I'm coding in Swift, but if you have a suggestion in Obj-C, I can translate. Thanks!

EDIT: I can confirm that this is caused by removing and re-adding the subviews of UIscrollView programmatically. Since I need to do that for functionality, any suggestions how to restore the auto-scroll?

EDIT: Here is the code of the test app version, that does not scroll automatically. I laid out the views and fields with storyboard, then remove and re-add programmatically.

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field4: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view3: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view4: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var fields = [UITextField]()
var views = [UIView]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fields = [field1, field2, field3, field4]
    views = [view1, view2, view3, view4]
    for v in views {
        v.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    var vConstraints = "V:|"
    for v in views {
        scrollView.addSubview(v)
        scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        let vIndex = find(views, v)! + 1
        vConstraints += "-8-[v\(vIndex)]"
    }
    vConstraints += "-8-|"
    scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(vConstraints, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["v1": view1, "v2": view2, "v3": view3, "v4": view4]))
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Comment: I'd not recommend U to rely on the built-in scrollview scrolling to the the active textField and rather write a couple of lines of code that will work for-sure. Default logic is limited and doesn't suite for some scenarios. User can scroll down the area that bellow the keyboard.(It works only if u jump to nextresponder by pushing "Next" on the keyboard ).  At first I'd recommend U to read an official  solution by Apple (end the end of the page): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: @David, I've been writing versions of that code for over a day now, with limited luck. For one thing, `scrollRectToVisible` also does nothing in my current setup.

Comment: I remember I also have tried using `scrollRectToVisible` but discarded 'cos it doesn't work if area is located in the visible rect. In `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method U can get the textField origin coordinates and calculate the scrollview offset

Comment: I was just hoping for the default logic because it would simplify the code. I am stuck on managing the keyboard, with a chicken-and-egg problem of not having the keyboard height to use in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, and if I put the code in the keyboard notification, it doesn't get called when moving between two fields with the same keyboard layout. I know that's all a totally separate question, and I'll keep working on it!

Comment: @David, I'd like to thank you for pushing me back towards the keyboard commands. I've got a solution, which while it doesn't answer the question of why we lose the built-in functionality on programmatic changes, does work for my app.

Comment: I understand U, but U gave up to early. Keyboard frame is always the same     (depends on device), but can change when orientation changes. ( observe it with `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`). If `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is triggered but keyboard size is unknown - save the activeTextField Y-position and handle scroll offset in the notification observer. Once U get the keyboard framesize - handle the scroll in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`. If orientation changes - observe this event too and adjust the offset with the new keyboardFrame.